# Integration with steps $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-u) \, du $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, convolution

> How do I solve this with steps?
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-u) \, du $$

where
$$f(t)=
\begin{cases}
 0& \text{if}\quad t<0\\
 1 & \text{if}\quad 0\leq t\leq1\\
 0 & \text{if}\quad t>1.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I have fixed your format; please review my edit.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what I wanted.

Comment: $f(t)$ is a "square function."  Sometimes it is called the $\Pi$ function.  The area under the square is $1.$  $f(t-u)$ is still a square function.  Adding a term will translate it horizontally, a negative sign will flip it along some vertical axis, but neither of those will change areas.  And the area under the square is still $1.$

Answer (score 1):

enforcing the change of variables $x=t-u\implies du=-dx$ then 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-u) \, du =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=  \int_{0}^1 \, dx=1$$

> Alternatively 
>   $$0\le t-u\le1 \Longleftrightarrow  t-1\le u \le t$$

Hence $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t-u) \, du =\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{[0,1]}(t-u) \, du=  \int_{t-1}^t \, du =1$$